# GetLastInputInfo() giving proper time

Tags: c++, mfc

I have written a code in OnTimer(), which is called every 100ms, and give me the time the application is staying idle here is the code

```
void MyAppView::OnTimer(UINT_PTR nIDEvent)
{
// TODO: Add your message handler code here and/or call default
if(nIDEvent == 3)
{
    // Get the last input event info.
    LASTINPUTINFO li;
    li.cbSize = sizeof(LASTINPUTINFO);
    ::GetLastInputInfo(&li);
    // Calculate the time elapsed in seconds.
    DWORD te = ::GetTickCount();
    int elapsed = (te - li.dwTime) / 100;
    // Test against a preset timeout period in
    // seconds.
    if(5000 < elapsed)
    {
        // Call a function or set an application flag
        // that can be acted on outside this function.
        AfxMessageBox(_T("This session has timeout"));
    }
  }
}
```

I dont know whats going wrong in this code, but i get elapsed=0 everytime.
Please let me know where am i going wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that the complete system didn't get any input in 500 seconds? GetLastInputInfo is system wide!

Comment: When you're stepping through this code in a debugger, you will produce input, resetting the idle counter. Try setting a [tracepoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/232dxah7(v=vs.90).aspx) instead of a breakpoint. There's nothing obvious wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a **float** calculation, not integer...

```
float elapsed = (te - li.dwTime) / 100.0;
```

Comment: -1 That doesn't change anything. It gives you extra precision where you don't need it. The OP wants to know, whether the elapsed time - expressed in 0.1s intervals - is greater than 500s. Whether you truncate during the division, or compare against an even integer doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Right. And I gave one possible answer. Your suggestion implies, that there was input within the last 0.1s. The OP is interested to time out the session after 500s. He seriously doesn't care about whether he is getting 0, 0.00001423876, 142.4548765, or another value. He doesn't care about fractions.